# Why don't power series methods work for linear ODE's with singularities?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

My math class tells me power series methods don't work for equations of the form

$$f'' +p(x)f' +q(x)f = 0$$

if the functions $p(x)$ or $q(x)$ have singularities at the point about which you're trying to expand. This creates a motivation for the Frobenius method, for equations of the form

$$f'' + \frac{p(x)}{x}f' +\frac{q(x)}{x^2}f = 0$$

or rearranged:

$$x^2f'' + xp(x) +q(x) = 0$$

Why won't regular power series methods work for equations of this form? If you generalize to a Laurent series, will the power series method work without using the Frobenius method? Any general answers about expanding about singular points would also be helpful.

Comment: Because power series are basically infinite polynomials. Each partial sum is a polynomial. Polynomials do not have singularities, so how can you expect to get a valid approximation?

Comment: Couldn't have said that better...

Comment: Is that still the case if we generalize to a Laurent series?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the simplest case, which is Euler's equation
$$
     x^{2}y''(x)+axy'(x)+by(x)=0,
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are constants. Euler's equation has at least one solution $x^{\alpha}$ which you can easily find by plugging this form into the equation. The power can be positive and fractional, which is still a problem for a power series. When there is a regular singular point, you can factor out one such power of $x$ and get a power series solution.